# Unable to migrate react-navigation from 5 to 6 for projects using `react-navigation/compat`

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

About the compat discussions in react-navigation's roadmap for v6
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8981

> the package will be removed from main branch but will stay on 5.x branch as well as npm, and will continue to work with 6.x.

I migrated react-navigation version from 4 to 5 before. In this time, I used `@react-navigation/compat`. It's working well.
Now, I wanted to migrate 5 to 6 with `@react-navigation/compat`. But occurs type error in bellow code. `createCompatNavigatorFactory(createStackNavigator)`. Unfortunately this looks like the correct error.

Do you have any good solutions to fix this error?

The versions

```
  "@react-navigation/compat": "5.3.20",
  "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.2",
  "@react-navigation/stack": "6.0.7",
```

Answer (score 1):

The compat package has been removed from the repository, since it was only related to v5.

If you want to use v6 you'll need to refactor your code and get rid of the compat help unfortunately.